# qunit test error with equal and deepEqual

Tags: javascript, tdd, qunit

I'm Trying to understand qunit testing

Why is this test failing? If I compare every property, are the same ...

```
    test("Get model equal", function () {

        function getModel() {

            function myModel() {
                this.name = "";
                this.address = "";
                this.phone = "";
            }

            return new myModel();
        }

        var model1 = getModel();
        var model2 = getModel();

        equal(model1, model2);

    });

    test("Get model deepEqual", function () {

        function getModel() {

            function myModel() {
                this.name = "";
                this.address = "";
                this.phone = "";
            }

            return new myModel();
        }

        var model1 = getModel();
        var model2 = getModel();

        deepEqual(model1, model2);

    });
```

Comment: Which of the comparisons is failing?

Comment: I make two tests now, both are failing ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/why-deepequal-is-not-working-in-this-test#14737000002953407

Answer (score 0):

The equality test is failing right? That's because they are two different instances, even though they contain the same data. For example, look at the examples on the QUnit documentation [here](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit/deepEqual).